# WiX uninstall assembly from GAC when file in use

Tags: dll, wix, gac

Using WiX 3.11 I've developed a simple installation file which installs one DLL in the global assembly cache:

```
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
  <Component Id="CMP_ABC" 
             Guid="XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX" 
             Permanent="no"
             Shared="yes" >
    <File Id="File_ABC" 
          Assembly=".net" 
          Source="ABC.dll" 
          KeyPath="yes" 
          Vital="yes"/>
  </Component>
</Directory>
```

Installation works and the file is placed in the GAC_32 folder. When trying to uninstall the package and the file is currently in use by a different process (loaded in Visual Studio for example), the file does not get uninstalled and the WiX installation package does not return any error:

```
MSI (s) (68:EC) [09:24:58:210]: MsiProvideAssembly is returning: 1607
MSI (s) (68:EC) [09:24:58:429]: Assembly Error:The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

MSI (s) (68:EC) [09:24:58:429]: Note: 1: 1935 2: {XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX} 3: 0x80070020 4: IAssemblyCache 5: UninstallAssembly 6: ABC,version="X.YY.ZZ.0",culture="neutral",publicKeyToken="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",processorArchitecture="x86"
MSI (s) (68:EC) [09:24:58:429]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: Error
MSI (s) (68:EC) [09:24:58:429]: Note: 1: 2228 2:  3: Error 4: SELECT `Message` FROM `Error` WHERE `Error` = 1935
```

The last line however always shows

```
MSI (c) (30:88) [09:24:59:505]: Product: ABC -- Configuration completed successfully.
```

Is it possible to fail the uninstallation if the file is currently in use or for some other reason cannot be removed?

Comment: As per this resource https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/app-domains/how-to-remove-an-assembly-from-the-gac, when you install an assembly in the GAC using Windows Installer, a reference count is maintained so that the assembly only gets removed when the count reaches zero. In your case Visual Studio did not install your assembly in the GAC, but having it opened in VS prevents Windows Installer from removing it. This is clearly mentioned in the error message given by MSI. Try closing Visual Studio and retry.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm trying to prevent, or at least have Windows Installer return an error that the file is in use.

If 'gacutil -u' can return an error when trying to remove the assembly, why shouldn't WiX be able to return that same error code?

Comment: Gacutil behaves differently than the Windows Installer (MSI) in this case, as they are not the same tool.

Comment: I understand, I'm just a bit disappointed that WiX does log the error that the file is in use, but does not let me act on it (i.e. fail the uninstallation).

I could of course add a custom action to my installer which checks the GAC to verify and see if the DLL was in fact removed but it seems like a workaround for something this trivial (just passing on the error code)

Comment: That's because it's not an error; It's work deferred until a reboot. If you want users to on it, give them a FilesInUse dialog.

Comment: FilesInUse dialog only works for window handles, since this is a DLL this functionality does not work.